# Can a Formula be Found for Aperiodically Oscillating Harmonic Series that Converge to Specific Real Numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

About a month ago, messing around with the Möbius function, I was inspired to explore something I called "mutwo" sequences and series. A mutwo sequence for a particular real number $N$ is $\{m(n;N)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and the corresponding mutwo series is
$$
M(x;N)=\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{m(n;N)}{n}\\
$$
where $M(\infty;N)=N$. The mutwo sequence is derived from the mutwo series by
$$
m(n+1;N)=\mathrm{sgn}(N-M(n;N))
$$
If $m(n;N)$ would be zero by this definition I just assign the negative of the previous value. Essentially, $M(x;N)$ hugs to the value of $N$ as closely as it can as it oscillates—usually aperiodically—and converges toward the value of $N$. As an example, here's a snip from the one for the euler-mascheroni constant:
$$
\{m(n;\gamma)\}_{n\geq1}=\{1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,...\}
$$

I've shown a few neat things so far: for $H_n\geq N$, or approximately $n>e^{N-\gamma}$, the series converges at the rate $|N-M(x;N)|\leq\frac1x$; one or both of $m(2n;N)+m(2n+1;N)$ or $m(2n+1;N)+m(2n+2;N)$ always equals zero for $n>e^{N-\gamma}$; some of the time, the mutwo sequences for the numbers $N$ and $N+\epsilon$ begin to differ around the term $\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$; and for $n>e^{N-\gamma}$, you cannot have more than two $1$'s or $-1$'s in a row.

My question is, can a formula for the mutwo sequence $m(n;N)$ be found for arbitrary $N$, such as $m(n;\ln(2))=-(-1)^n$? I would like to find something that *doesn't* depend on every previous value of $m$ like my definition does, if that makes it any clearer.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in much the same way as me trying to parallel park :-P.

Say you are given the numbers $1$, $1/2$, $1/3$, $1/4$, etc and you are aiming for a sum of $0$.

Starting from that value, you first add terms with positive signs just until you are over the target, in this case that occurs with just the term $+1$. So now, add negative terms just until you go under:

$(+1)+(-1/2)+(-1/3)+(-1/4)=(-1/12).$

You then add $+1/5$ to go over $0$ again, followed by $-1/6$ and $-1/7$ to go under, and so on.

At each stage the absolute difference from your target is less than that of the last term you used; for instance $(+1)+(-1/2)+(-1/3)+(-1/4)=(-1/12)$, where you stop when the sum just becomes less than the target $0$, is off the mark by less than $1/4$. Since the terms converge to zero, you thus squeeze yourself to the target with the judicious choice of signs.

Comment: It's a great method to construct the series for an arbitrary number, but I don't know if I would be grasping for too much by chasing after some formula that could produce any term in the series on a whim—regardless of knowledge of previous terms—as is the case for $m(n;ln(2))=-(-1)^n$; that's my ultimate goal here.